# Deno unit testing error No such file or directory (os error 2)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, deno

Hey dont know if im being silly im trying to learn unit testing with deno and keep getting this error im using puppeteer if thats relevant cant figure out whats wrong it seems to be pointing to the await in this line

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })

```
Deno.test('log in with invalid username/password', async test => {
    // GIVEN I am on the "Log In" page
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
            const page = await browser.newPage()
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
            await page.click('a[href="/login"]', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    // WHEN I enter "fakeuser" in the username field
            await page.type('input[name="username"]', 'fakeuser')
    // AND I enter "fakepassword" in the password field
            await page.type('input[name="password"]', 'fakepassword')
    // AND I click on the login button
            await page.click('input[type="submit"]', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    // THEN I should be returned to the "Log In" page
            const heading = await page.$eval('h1', node => node.innerText)
            await assertEquals(heading, 'Log In', 'invalid credentials dont send user back to login page')
            await browser.close()
})
```

[error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE6eY.png)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to me that puppeteer throws an error when trying to load your html-file of the login page or the page you're refering to when submitting your login form.

But there is to little information given in order to make a qualified response.

Could you please provide more background information as well as tell the specific line with the line number 72. In line 72 the error is being brought up in your test file. (Note that the line number could have been changed since your post if you added or deleted some lines in your test file, so check the line number in a fresh error output.)